# NotFoundHttpException in Laravel 5 project

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a newbie building a webapp using laravel 5, but got stuck with a `NotFoundHttpException`. I looked at several similar questions but could not solve the problem.

**My routes/web.php file**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::post('/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
        'as'=> 'signup'
    ]);
});
```

**app\Http\Controllers\UserController:**

```
class UserController extends Controller {

public function postSignUp(Request $request){
    $email = $request['email'];
    $username = $request['username'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

    $user = new User();
    $user -> email = $email;
    $user -> username = $username;
    $user -> password = $password;

    $user -> save();

    return redirect() -> back();
}

public function postSignIn(){

}
}
```

I am sending the request like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
```

I checked for any typos several times but couldn't find any. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This only happens when you are submitting the form?

Comment: I don't normally include the beginning `/` (except for the root route). You could try removing that from your signup route.

Comment: Yes, I get the error when I try to submit the form.

edit: removing the `/` doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: When you get the error, what is the URL in your browser?

Comment: First step after $email insert: return $email: and check if email data is arriving to the controller, second step  change your return to: return back ();  let me know what value return the first step